# Fullcalendar - Remove day suffix in dayGridMonth View when using Japanese

Tags: fullcalendar, cjk

When setting locale to Japanese in Fullcalendar and use dayGridMonth View, for each day cell suffix "日"(means day) is added.

I want to remove this day suffix letter, so that the appearance of the cell would be just numbers.

I looked through the document but I couldn't find it.

This behavior can be checked in official demo by setting locale to "ja".
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale-demo

I want my day cells to show only numbers, without suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the source code of FullCalendar. It uses **Intl.DateTimeFormat** to convert date format as below.

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/f86b5f33148cb43178e21c46a6ea814d128a88e1/src/core/datelib/formatting-native.ts#L165

I couldn't find how to customize the format. A possible dirty hack is to fork the repository and remove "日" character after following code.

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/e73621e5c9bcf6778c07cc5a29a4b0641d3ac46e/src/daygrid/DayGrid.ts#L390-L395

```
html = html.replace('日', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Since it is using Intl API, a hack like yours seems to be required.  I will have a try!

Answer (score 0):

There's a option called **dayCellDidMount** in FullCalendar, which could be called for do something after dayCell has been added.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks

So you could replace the original dayText with your custom Text when call this.

code for example:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...,
dayCellDidMount: function(info){              
          var day = moment(info.date).format('DD') // custom the text for example

          // hide the original one
          var originElement = info.el.querySelectorAll(".fc-daygrid-day-number")
          originElement.forEach(e => e.classList.add("d-none")  ); 
          
          // insert new text
          var targetElement = info.el.querySelectorAll(".fc-daygrid-day-top");
          targetElement.forEach(e => e.innerHTML = day );
      },
})
```

and then you can customize css **.fc-daygrid-day-top** for the view.